# how to check if Directory.EnumerateFiles does not produce any results

Tags: c#

I have a function that checks for presence of files in a particular folder and if the files have the data that is not present in the main database i write that data to main db and delete the file i am using Directory.EnumerateFiles to get the list of files and then i iterate through this list to check if they are present in the db, i want to return from the function if the list is empty how to check if list that i got is empty,if i debug and the folder has no files it shows Enumeration did not produce the results.

```
    private void GetListOfFiles()
    {
        string sourceDirectory = pathOfXmlFiles;
        if (!Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory))
        {
            return;
        }
        var xmlFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.xml");
        foreach (var item in xmlFiles)
        {
            ReadXmlFile(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in xmlFiles)
        {
            if (_writtenToDb)
            {
                File.Delete(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

i check for the presence of these files using a different thread that has a timer that fires every 25 seconds , i never do stop the timer can this lead to memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. If `xmlFiles` is empty both `foreach` loops won't do anything since there are no objects to iterate over.

However, if you really need to explicitly return if there are no files, use this:

```
if(!xmlFiles.Any())
    return;
```

Dont forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source file.

---

As you are enumerating multiple times over the returned files, I suggest you use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) instead. This will return an array with all files. This will avoid multiple hits to the disk for querying the existing files.

Comment: i check for the presence of these files using a different thread that has a timer that fires every 25 seconds , i never do stop the timer can this lead to memory leaks?

Comment: @PradeepSingh: This is a new question. Please post it as such.